# "throw NotImplementedException" from Base or dynamic_cast to derived types?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I've a hierarchy of classes that resembles something like this:

```
class Schedule
{
    chrono::time_point GetStartTime();
    chrono::seconds GetDuration();
    DeviceID GetDeviceID();
}

class DeviceSchedule : public Schedule
{
    DeviceState GetDeviceState();
    DeviceIntensity GetDeviceIntensity();
}

class SensorSchedule : public Schedule
{
    float GetTemperature();
    float GetHumidity();
}
```

There's a Scheduler class which knows what type of Schedule to construct and adds it to a list<shared_ptr<Schedule>> and there's a different thread that wakes up and executes the Schedule at some later time.

Basically, the executing thread needs access to different types of data depending on what type of schedule is being executed. To do this, I've come up with 3 approaches:

1. dynamic_cast to each Derived type and check for NULL
2. dynamic_cast based on a pure virtual GetScheduleType() function in the base Schedule class
3. Implement all derived functions in the base class to throw a NotImplementedException so that if the executioner tries to call GetTemperature on a DeviceSchedule, the code would crash. (There's enough logging to nail the bug if that ever happened!)

I'm leaning towards a dynamic_cast with the GetScheduleType() virtual function but that doesn't seem exactly pretty. But, maybe, this is a textbook case of why the dynamic_cast exists. What is the most correct way of handling this situation?

I've seen answers on SO that dislike both, dynamic_cast as well as the NotImplementedException approach, adding to my existing confusion :-).

(Note that this is a simplified example. In reality, there's about 4-5 different types of Schedules with about 4-5 properties on each of them, if it matters.)

Comment: Why have a common base class if the classes have nothing in common? If the handling is totally different, I would have 4-5 different lists and have the scheduler work its way through them, one at a time. No casts needed.

Comment: Or use a variant type, if the number of types you need to handle is fixed.

Comment: Perhaps your design of the class hierarchy is flawed? This is a case where I would use multiple inheritance, with abstract `Device` and `Sensor` classes that are inherited by the respective scheduler class. Then have functions taking pointers or references to the abstract base-classes, and do the work specifically needed for that type of schedule.

Comment: Or perhaps use [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Encapsulation) to have the respective scheduler child-class contain (non-abstract) instances of some `Device` or `Sensor`. Then from the base `Scheduler` class they override a pure virtual `DoSomething` function that then does whatever needs to be done when the schedule triggers.

Comment: @BoPersson, there are a few properties common to all types of Schedules.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Multiple inheritance? I thought that was harmful in most cases and I don't really know if this qualifies as an exception.

Comment: Using multiple inheritance to inherit an *interface* from a pure abstract class is almost never harmful. Even the fabled diamond-pattern is not a problem, unless one of the base-classes *implements* one of the interface functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, none of Schedule, Device or Sensor can be pure abstract in my case, imo. They all have concrete properties. For eg, GetStartTime() will have to be implemented in the base Schedule class. Or am I blatantly missing something?

Comment: I mean you have an abstract `Device` class, which defines the *interface only*. Then you have the `DeviceSchedule` which *implements* the interface, together with whatever member variables are needed. The base `Schedule` class can't be abstract as it implements the actual scheduler.

Comment: That said, I actually think my second possible solution might be better.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yeah, that does make sense. Except, life is never that simple ;-). The Scheduler only understands the scheduling aspect of things. It doesn't and shouldn't know about how to actually tell a device what to do. So, it maintains a list and when its time to do something, queues a Schedule object to some other class which carries out that action. I generally prefer having the class that holds the data to take actions on it but in this case, there's 2 types of data and the Scheduler only knows how to handle one of them. Having said that, I will try and think on those lines!

Comment: That's where a virtual `perform_action` function in `Schedule` comes handy: If you override it in the child-classes, then the scheduler just calls it and the child-class implementation can do whatever it wants.